# Wordpress Launcher on Google Cloud Platform - 404 Error

Tags: google, wordpress, cloud

I'm testing out the Google Cloud Platform - normally I use dedicated servers and handle everything manually. So it's a bit different for me to press a button and have a utility set up all the settings.

I created a new WordPress blog on a brand new URL. In general it went swimmingly - the blog popped live, uses my new URL, and displays the content.

You can look at individual pages for entries, move through them, and so on.

However, bizarrely, if you look at the bottom of the main page where there is the "1", "2", and so on for the pages of posts, THOSE do not work. It says:

The requested URL /page/2/ was not found on this server.

It's on the exact same URL and everything else works fine. Why would this one normal feature not work? Any ideas? I've tried googling around for answers and am stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To fix your specific error that you show, consider making a folder in document root called "page" and in that folder you can create a folder called "2". In that folder create the default index page. (likely index.html or index.htm).

If that fails to work, check your server configuration files (such as .htaccess files) to make sure there is nothing that reformats URLs. For example, the RewriteRule lines can control the outcome to URLs without querying the server file system.

If that doesn't work, then delete or rename all special configurations (including any .htaccess files) and follow my first idea, and things should work.

Comment: I don't think I want to be making a folder for every single page - what happens when I get up to 20 pages of posts? 30? Will I have to be hand-creating pages every time I get over a multiple of 10? It seems better to fix the underlying error than trap myself in a lifetime of hand creating new pages as I add more posts.

Comment: only other thing I could suggest is to use a platform your wordpress launcher is compatible with since wordpress uses server-side software (like php) and depending on the setup, it may require a special setup on the server end which I believe what wordpress tries to do when you install any of its features. Have you tried another server besides google cloud?